# Highstock: On Series Flags that are inverted

Tags: highcharts

I looking to place Flags on the Series([as in the HighCharts demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement)). Except I want the flags to be upside down(i.e. it should be placed below the series) [like this (excuse the MS Paint rendition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heDjW.png).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`flags.y`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags.y). See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nx4at8y2/ and code:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        id: 'dataseries',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        y: 30, // default to -30
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
            title: 'A',
            text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
    }]
```